# How to rotate nodes of phylogeny in R without overlapping?

Tags: r, rotation, phylogeny, ape-phylo

I'm trying to make nice figures for my phylogenies in R (I'm working my way up to using R for analyses). The trees have been made in Garli and MrBayes. The Garli (maximum likelihood) trees have been behaving with all the typical ape, phytools, and phangorn commands. I've got them with colors, clade labels, node labels, etc.

But my MrBayes trees are NOT behaving.
EDIT - now another one of my Garli trees is also not cooperating.

The nodes won't rotate properly. Is there something else I need to do differently?

Here is an example:

```
mbcpart <- read.nexus("acronicta_101_taxa.nex.con.tre")
outgroup <- c("Nacna_malachitis", "Nacna_sugitanii", "Gerbathodes_paupera", "Belciades_niveola", "Moma_kolthoffi", "Moma_alpium")
rmbcpart <- root(mbcpart, outgroup, resolve.root=TRUE)
rmbcpart <- rotate(rmbcpart, 175)
rmbcpart <- rotate(rmbcpart, 122)
rmbcpart <- rotate(rmbcpart, 108)
```

Then I make a new window and plot the thing. 
Attached are two trees side by side. The one on the right is the original, without rotating. The one on the left is after the rotating. It looks like they are **mostly** rotated, but a few taxa get dragged away or left behind. This results in overlapping branches.

Does anyone have any idea what I could do to fix this?

[image: bad mrbayes]

Comment: Provide an example tree that is not "behaving" so that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: If you can provide a [mcve], we can help you. If you provide the newick string of your tree, we can replicate the problem and see what's causing it.

Comment: I sent all my code to a friend, who wasn't able to replicate the error - using the exact same file and code, it worked just fine for her. So... maybe it's an issue with R studio that I'm using? I can't think of any reason why it's acting up.

Comment: It could be indeed a problem with R studio and Quartz. Alternatively, it could be a problem with the polytomies (e.g. node 106) maybe try "solving/unsolving" them using `tree <- di2multi(multid2di(tree))`. In both cases the bug seems pretty weird and probably stems from something else. I suggest you share a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as suggest by @C_Z_.

Answer (score 0):

When I have encountered this problem, I was able to resolve the issue by rotating the nodes before rooting the tree. E.g.:

```
mbcpart <- read.nexus("acronicta_101_taxa.nex.con.tre")
rmbcpart <- rotate(rmbcpart, 175)
rmbcpart <- rotate(rmbcpart, 122)
rmbcpart <- rotate(rmbcpart, 108)
outgroup <- c("Nacna_malachitis", "Nacna_sugitanii", "Gerbathodes_paupera", "Belciades_niveola", "Moma_kolthoffi", "Moma_alpium")
rmbcpart <- root(mbcpart, outgroup, resolve.root=TRUE)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is really just a function that wraps a hack, but I recommend trying phytools::untangle. E.g.:

```
library(phytools)
tree<-untangle(tree,"read.tree")
```